# How to do a CNAME record lookup in swift

Tags: swift, core-foundation, dns-sd

I found some [example code](https://gist.github.com/fikeminkel/a9c4bc4d0348527e8df3690e242038d3) online that I'm trying to use to do a CNAME record lookup (notice that I pass a `callback` block that I want to be run):

```
DNSServiceQueryRecord(serviceRef, 0, 0, domainName, UInt16(kDNSServiceType_CNAME), UInt16(kDNSServiceClass_IN), callback, &mutableCompletionHandler);
DNSServiceProcessResult(serviceRef.pointee)
```

The problem is that this code is getting blocked at `DNSServiceProcessResult(serviceRef.pointee)` and the `callback` is never called. According to Apple's documentation for [DNSServiceProcessResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd/1804696-dnsserviceprocessresult), I need to

> Use `DNSServiceRefSockFD` in conjunction with a run loop or select() to determine the presence of a response from the server before calling this function to process the reply without blocking.

So I looked at `DNSServiceRefSockFD` and found that I could create a `dnssd_sock_t` with `DNSServiceRefSockFD(serviceRef.pointee)`. But now that I have the socket, I'm not sure how to "use it in conjunction with a run loop" as an event source for the run loop (according to the [DNSServiceRefSockFD](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dnssd/1804698-dnsservicerefsockfd?language=objc) documentation).

I'm just not understanding how this works. I don't understand how to use the `dnsssd_sock_t` as an event source to a run loop so that I can call `DNSServiceProcessResult` at the right time without blocking so that my `callback` will actually run.

If it's better to use the socket as a kqueue event source or in a select() loop (as the documentation mentions), I'm fine with that, but I don't know how to do that either.

CoreFoundation can be quite cryptic, so any help is much appreciated!

And if there's a better way to do a CNAME record lookup then, by all means, please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my (ethan-gerardot) comments on https://gist.github.com/fikeminkel/a9c4bc4d0348527e8df3690e242038d3

The first paragraph answers how to get the callback to be called without blocking.